# Mongoose not updating embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, document, mongoose

I quite a problem while I'm attempting to update an embedded document in mongodb. I've tried two methods and neither work, and I've searched everywhere for reasons why this it's not updating. Anyway, my schema looks like this (I may note that the embedded document I'm trying to update is a Mixed type).

```
var UserModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    account: String,
    salt: String,
    password: String,
    highlight_words: String,
    networks: {},
    ip: String,
    ident: String,
    is_connected: Boolean,
    account_type: String
});
```

I've tried updating 'networks' with these two snippets of code and neither work. I'm about to pull my hair out.

```
self.userModel.update({account: key}, {networks: self.client_data[key]['networks']}, function(err) {});
```

And (note that I've tried adding a callback to save(), and it executes without error)

```
self.userModel.findOne({account: key}, function(err, doc) {
    doc.networks = self.client_data[key]['networks'];
    doc.markModified('networks').save();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:

The problem was that the object was like so `{'some.thing': {more: 'stuff'}}` obviously it didn't like the . which is understandable!

Comment: What is the value of `self.client_data[key]['networks']`? Try replacing it with some literals to help your debugging.

Comment: It's quite a large object, I know for a fact it's populated though. I tried replacing it with `doc.networks = {test: 123};` and that still didn't save the document..

Comment: In the first version too, I'm guessing? Any chance it's just not matching anything? Does `delete({account: key})` work?

Answer (score 11):

Try `doc.markModified('networks');`. It looks like `networks` is a schemaless type. Mongoose can't autodetect changes to schemaless types.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your schema fully for this to work. For example:

networks {
     type : "String"
}